# specified component is not get rendered using routerlink in angular

Tags: angular

[router ink is added on a div also imported the router Module in the news module, URL is get changed but respective page is not get rendered you can refer 2nd screenshot for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7bkP.png)
[here page URL gets the news-details but page is not get rendered previous URL was localhost:4200/home/news-list and after click on div URL is localhost:4200/home/news-list//news-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrP9L.png)

Comment: Some suggestions: Don't send screenshots of code, but post code inside ``` blocks in the question instead - Create a stackblitz of the project - Check your browser console for errors and report them in the question too

Answer (score 0):

please check whether you have  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag
in your component or not